# Mongodb - Add geoNear to an existing query to sort by distance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There are 3 collections for this application

1. users - all user details
2. partnership - user relation to each other
3. location - user geolocation

I have 1 and 2 working. The 3rd task is to sort the resuling users list by distance from a given coordinate.

Here is the mongo playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/XELySm8KGpM

```
    db={
  users: [
    {
      _id: "abc",
      name: "abc",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "xyz",
      name: "xyyy",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "123",
      name: "yyy",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr",
      name: "tttt",
      group: 1
    },
    {
      _id: "eee",
      name: "uuu",
      group: 1
    }
  ],
  partnership: [
    {
      _id: "abc_123",
      fromUser: "abc",
      toUser: "123"
    },
    {
      _id: "eee_rrr",
      fromUser: "eee",
      toUser: "rrr"
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr_abc",
      fromUser: "rrr",
      toUser: "abc"
    },
    {
      _id: "abc_rrr",
      fromUser: "abc",
      toUser: "rrr"
    },
    {
      _id: "xyz_rrr",
      fromUser: "xyz",
      toUser: "rrr"
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr_eee",
      fromUser: "rrr",
      toUser: "eee"
    },
    
  ],
  locations: [
    {
      _id: "123",
      location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          54.23,
          67.12
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      _id: "rrr",
      location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          51.23,
          64.12
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      _id: "eee",
      location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          55.23,
          62.12
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      _id: "abc",
      location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          53.23,
          67.12
        ]
      }
    },
    
  ]
}
```

The following query by itself works. How to integrate it to the query in the playground?

```
  {
    $geoNear: {
       near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 41.99279 , -81.719296 ] },
       distanceField: "dist.calculated",
       spherical: true
    }
  },
```

Comment: `$geoNear` can only be the first step in an aggregation pipeline, so you need to first sort by distance and then do all the other things. This means your schema is not very efficient for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$geoNear` can only be the first step in an aggregation pipeline, so you need to first sort by distance and then do all the other things. This means your schema is not very efficient for this.

One option is:

```
db.locations.aggregate([
   {$geoNear: {
       near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 41.99279 , -81.719296 ] },
       distanceField: "calculatedDist",
       spherical: true
    }
  },
  {$lookup: {
      from: "partnership",
      let: {user_id: "$_id"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {
              $or: [
                {$and: [{$eq: ["$fromUser", "rrr"]}, {$eq: ["$toUser", "$$user_id"]}]},
                {$and: [{$eq: ["$toUser", "rrr"]}, {$eq: ["$fromUser",
                        "$$user_id"]}]},
                
              ]
        }}}
      ],
      as: "valid"
    }
  },
  {$match: {"valid.0": {$exists: true}}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
  }},
  {$project: {user: {$first: "$user"}, calculatedDist: 1}},
  {$sort: {calculatedDist: 1}},
  {$group: {_id: 0, users: {$push: "$user"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/icDdQ3V1_mO)

Comment: Thanks. Would you suggest anyway I can make this more efficient? Will moving all locations to the `users` collection and eliminating `locations` collections help?

Comment: Sure, if location is saved on the user this is more efficient. If the partnership will include array of [fromUser, toUser] instead of two different fields, this will also help here, since you want the partnership regardless if the user is the `fromUser` or the `toUser`

Comment: In this case it will be simple as [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XRRhk_XenWc)

Comment: ok, I will move location to the user collection.

Comment: Question - How did you get `calculatedDist` for each user and how did you create a `2dsphere index` in mongoplayground?

Comment: Since I can't use `$geoNear` in the mongoplayground, I put it in a mark and just put the `calculatedDist` in the input. The real query should include the `$geoNear` step like my answer here.

Comment: Thanks. One last question. How to check if value exists in users array element 0 or 1 in partnership collection. `$in: ["$$user_id", "$users"]` - So instead of `$users` I want to check `$users[0] or $users[1]`

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but you can use `$arrayElemAt`

Comment: I would like to only show users that `rrr` has not liked before. So in those cases `rrr` will be the first array element in partnership collection

Comment: In this case you can keep the previous structure of `fromUser` and `toUser`

Comment: Unfortunately for the `fromUser`, `toUser` concept, I had to start from partnership collection. Here for nearby to work I have to start from `users` collection. - Previous working playground - https://mongoplayground.net/p/cXhAyK3bgCb

Comment: I created a new question as its diffrent functionality - Can you pls suggest how I can start this query from `users` collection so I can do geoNear? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73910975/mongodb-how-to-sort-by-distance-using-geonear-in-addition-to-looking-up-anothe